# Html extension method not working in form

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{        
    Html.SubmitButton(); //doesn't work
}
@*@Html.SubmitButton(); //does work*@
```

The extension method looks like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return new MvcHtmlString("<input type = \"submit\" value = \"Cancel\" />");
}
```

Why is the input element HTML able to be generated outside the using block but not inside it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missing the leading `@` which tells razor to output the results to the view. When you use just `Html.SubmitButton();`, the method is executed and the result is returned, but nothing is done with it.

Your code needs to be

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{        
    @Html.SubmitButton()
}
```